# Inverse Problem for jet equations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, jets

The following is a well known fact and due to the functorial properties of the jet functor:

Suppose you have two smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ and maps $f:M \rightarrow N$ as well as
$g: M \rightarrow N$, then if there is a $m \in M$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $m$ in $M$ such that the equation

$$f(x) = g(x)$$

holds on $U$ then clearly $j^1_mf = j^1_mg$.

The inverse Problem is when you have
jet equivalence classes $j^1_mf, j^1_mg \in J^1_m(M,N)$ with 
$$j_mf = j_mg$$

then is there an open neighbourhood $U$ of $m$ in $M$ and representatives $f \in j_mf$ as well as $g \in j_mg$ such that the equation $f(x) = g(x)$ holds on $U$ ?

Surely there are, but what is the argument in situations like this? (The functor properties of $J^1$ doesn't really fits here I guess, because the problem is inverse)

The point is, that I can't come up with a formal correct argument and when the situation gets more involved it is hard to say if the inverse question has a solution or not, due to the lack of an correct argument.

For example:

Suppose you have smooth manifolds and jet equivalence classes

$$j_{m_1}^1f \in J^1_{m_1}(M_1,N_1)$$
$$j_{m_2}^1h \in J^1_{m_2}(M_2,N_2)$$
$$j_{n_1}^1g_1, j_{n_1}^1g_2  \in J^1_{n_1}(N_1,N_2)$$
$$j_{m_1}^1k_1,j_{m_1}^1k_2 \in J^1_{m_1}(M_1,M_2)$$

(with $k_1(m_1) = m_2 = k_2(m_1)$, $f(m_1)=n_1$, $g_1(n_1)=h(m_2)=g_2(n_2)$  and a system of two jet equation of first order jets

$$j^1_{n_1}g_1 \circ j^1_{m_1}f = j^1_{m_2} h \circ j^1_{m_1}k_1$$
$$j^1_{n_1}g_2 \circ j^1_{m_1}f = j^1_{m_2} h \circ j^1_{m_1}k_2$$

and you know that this equation holds! So the question is not whether or
not the jets satisfy the equation, but the equation is taken for granted.

But the inverse problem is the question whether or not there are appropriate reprensentatives $g_1' \in j^1_{n_1}$ $\ldots$ (and all others) and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $m_1$ in $M_1$ such that

$$g_1 \circ f(x) = h \circ k_1(x)$$
$$g_2 \circ f(x) = h \circ k_2(x)$$

holds on $U$.

THis last example is not obvious and a formal argument is really needed.

Comment: Way too much abstraction here. You're talking about one point and a neighborhood of it. Do everything in local co-ordinate, and it's all very easy and clear. You can't answer this question without using the actual definition of a "jet".

Comment: Don't see how this will help. In local coordinates the jet equations are 'matrix equations' involving the Jacobi-matrices. But I still can't see how this lifts to the function equations. 

Can you give a little more details please?

Comment: Maybe the answer is even easier... By definition you have a representative for $j^1_mf$ in some small neighborhood $U$ of $m$. Since $j^1_mf=j^1_mg$, just take the same representative for $g$.

Comment: diverietti is, of course, right. $j^1_mf$ is by definition an equivalence class, and you can't have an empty equivalence class. But you might as well write all the "matrix equations" out explicitly and write down explicit formulas for everything. By the way, presumably you know the answer when $M$ and $N$ are 1-dimensional, right?

Comment: @dverietti: That only applies to the first example and as I said that is an easy situation. Nevertheless this is not really an argument for situations like the second example.
  

Comment: @Deane: Suppose we have the matrix equation (what is really the same thing as the jet equation), then what? How to get to the function equations? Some sort of partial differential equation solving process? Please point me to how to get from the Jacobi matrix level (the infinitesimal level) to the local level

Comment: Aren't you done once you solve the matrix equation? By taking local coordinates you reduce to considering maps between Euclidean spaces and since you are only looking at $j^1$ you just need to consider linear maps, which are uniquely determined by their derivative at the origin. 

Comment: Nevermind, please write out the details in co-ordinates and show us where you get stuck. I'd be happy to help with that.

Comment: Willie, indeed. There's no work to be done here. Everything being asked follows directly from the definition of a jet.

Comment: Ok.. Now I see whats the problem here. I made a mistake in writing the question! Sorry for that. Please read the second example again, I changed it.

Comment: Please note that this is NOT about solving the jet equations! The question is of different nature: The jet equation is supposed to hold.

Here it is about the associated function equation. I think tat wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume $U$ is a co-ordinate chart, the answer is yes. Simply choose local co-ordinates everywhere and assume each of your functions is an affine function of the co-ordinates. In that case, each function is equal to its own 1-jet map. So the desired equations involving the composition of functions follow directly from the 1-jet equations.

If you assume that, say, $f_1$, $f_2$, $h_1$, $h_2$ are given in advance and you want to solve for $g$, then this approach does not necessarily work. But, given suitable nondegeneracy assumptions on these functions, you can use the inverse function theorem to find local co-ordinates so that these functions become affine functions of the co-ordinates and therefore you can solve for $g$ as an affine function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Restated in coordinates: Suppose you have (smooth) functions $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $h_1,h_2:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^l$ AND YOU ALREADY KNOW that they satisfy the following
system of (matrix)-equations:

$$\frac{\partial f_1^\mu}{\partial x_\nu}(x') = J_j^\mu \cdot
\frac{\partial h_1^j}{\partial x_\nu}(x')$$
$$\frac{\partial f_2^\mu}{\partial x_\nu}(x') = J_j^\mu \cdot
\frac{\partial h_2^j}{\partial x_\nu}(x')$$

at a point $x'$ with $x=h_1(x')=h_2(x')$ for a given $(l \times m)$ matrix $J$. Regarding $J$ as the coordinate representation of a jet at $x$, the question is, whether or not there is a (local) function $g: \mathbb{R}^l \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with Jacobi matrix $J$ at $x$ such that

$$f_1(t) = g\circ h_1(t)$$ 
$$f_2(t) = g\circ h_2(t)$$

holds.

Comment: But isn't this question different from the original one? In the original one, you say that only the 1-jets at a given point of $f_1$, $f_2$, $g$, and $h$ are given and ask whether they can be extended to functions. Here, you say that the functions $f_1$, $f_2$, and $h$ are given and ask if the $1$-jet solution to $g$ can be extended to a function. The two questions are rather different.

Comment: No, I'm still looking for functions with given Jacobians. Here I'm looking for the functions $g$ with Jacobian $J$ at a point. Stating the the function $f_i$ and $h_i$ are known is not important. I just wrote it to point in the direction I'm looking at

Comment: I just did this because it looked to me, that you don't get the idea. But in you last comment (@Deane) you are right: The question is wether or not the Jacobians could be 'extended' (better lifted or even integrated) to functions, having theses these Jacobians at a given point. The point here is, that comments about 'solving the matrix equation' doesn't makes sense to me at all, so I gave another example that is a little more simple but of the same kind.
 

Comment: The two questions (the original one and the one in the answer) and therefore their answers are quite different. Could you edit your original question to reflect what you really want?